# VLC update download gives an error "while extracting the archive"

Tags: macos, error, vlc, auto-update

On a Mac Sierra, the VLC embedded update feature seems to work fine at first

```
Downloading update ... 42.1MB
```

and the download completes. However, just after, VLC gives an error

```
Update Error!
An error occurred while extracting the archive. Please try again later.
```

Is there any way to use a workaround (that VLC bug)?

Or does somebody know where VLC does download its update file? (not in `~Downloads`) there is maybe an access rights problem.

(without having to reinstall VLC)

Comment: This happens from time to time, best to just download the latest full version and upgrade that way.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to find out what happens exactly. Knowing where the file is downloaded would help...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with multiple software updates, and it turned out Disk Arbitrator tool was causing them. Fix was to disabling it temporarily until finishing the update.